# can i underscore a url path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, polymorphic-associations

I want to dynamically set the url path of a

```
  - application_path = @object.class.name.underscore + "_path"
  = link_to "<input type='button' value='Cancel' class ='bigbutton go_back'/>".html_safe, application_path(@application)
```

but i keep getting

```
 undefined method `application_path' for #<#<Class:0x00000103d11d80>:0x00000103d04a68>
```

any ideas on how to achieve this behavior

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the general case, you can use [Object#send](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-send) to call a method based on a symbol (which you can get from a string using `to_sym`):

```
send(application_path.to_sym, @application)
```

From the docs:

> **send(symbol [, args...]) → obj**
>
> Invokes the method identified by symbol, passing it any arguments specified.

But in this case, because your dynamic string is simple enough, Rails has a built-in method to do this, [url_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-url_for):

```
url_for(@application)
```

Example from the docs:

> ```
> <%= url_for(@workshop) %>
> # calls @workshop.to_param which by default returns the id
> # => /workshops/5
> ```

*Note: this is assuming your `@application` is a model object where the route matches the model name. In your code there seems to be two instance variables, `@object` and `@application`, but you haven't explained them fully, so you may need to modify the above to pass in `@object` instead of `@application`.*

Answer (score 0):

The method `url_for` does exactly what you're trying to do.

```rb
url_for(@application)
```